Error `bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0`
I have prepared the query as
await db.runSql(   
  `PREPARE fetchDashboards (text, text, text) AS SELECT \* FROM dashboards WHERE tenant_id = $1 AND user_id = $2 AND name = $3`,
 );

and when I try to execute it
const dashboardResult = await db.runSql(  
  'EXECUTE fetchDashboards($1, $2, $3)',  
  [filter.tenant_id, filter.user_id, filter.dashboard_name], 
);

I got the following error

Error during migration: error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0
at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/saaifali/JourneyWithSensys/web/node_modules/.pnpm/pg-protocol@1.7.0/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:283:98)
at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/saaifali/JourneyWithSensys/web/node_modules/.pnpm/pg-protocol@1.7.0/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:122:29)
at Parser.parse (/Users/saaifali/JourneyWithSensys/web/node_modules/.pnpm/pg-protocol@1.7.0/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:35:38)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/saaifali/JourneyWithSensys/web/node_modules/.pnpm/pg-protocol@1.7.0/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:191:23) {
length: 137,
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '08P01',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: undefined,
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'postgres.c',
line: '1724',
routine: 'exec_bind_message'
}

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated

Why are you trying to define a Postgres server side prepared statement from your JavaScript code?

Why not just const dashboardResult = await db.runSql('SELECT * FROM dashboards WHERE tenant_id = $1 AND user_id = $2 AND name = $3',  [filter.tenant_id, filter.user_id, filter.dashboard_name], );

The only statements you can use with parameters are SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE and VALUES. EXECUTE is not on that list, hence the error. The EXECUTE statement has to contain the literal parameter values.

... which is obviously a dangerous risk of injection.

@Charlieface ... if you don't do it right, yes.
